# in a nuxtjs spa, how to link the assets with relative urls?

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js

When a nuxtjs app in spa mode is built, the assets are referenced at `/_nuxt/vendor.a0f2fda15695e202a186.js` in `index.html`.

Is it possible to reference to those files with a relative url (without the first slash)?

(something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="_nuxt/vendor.a0f2fda15695e202a186.js"></script>`)

Comment: Hey Francois, did you got the answer for this?

Comment: @Master.Deep just what you can read here.

Answer (score 11):

## 1. Is it possible to reference to those files with a relative url?

Probably not.

See
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1380

## 2. The real problem

The reason you want a "relative path" to your assets is because your SPA (or  your assets) are not at the root directory of your domain. For example:

Your SPA is NOT at https://my-domain.com/

But at https://my-domain.com/my-app/

## 3. The solution

Go to `nuxt.config.js` and edit the following properties.

```
build: {
    // Set the absolute path where the assets are.
    // https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#publicpath
    publicPath: 'https://my-domain.com/my-app/',
},

router: {
    // Set the "Base" of the router.
    // https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#base
    base: '/my-app/'
},

link: [
    // Do this if you have files that are located at /static/
    // https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets#static
    {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        type: 'text/css',
        href: '/my-app/myStyleSheet.css'
    }
]
```

## 4. Reference

- https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#publicpath
- https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#base
- https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets#static

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I don't know the final url where the app is going to stay… that's why I can not use the `publicPath` and would prefer a relative url.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the **base** parameter to "my-app" in the router config of nuxt.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
 router: {
   base: '/my-app/'
 }
}
```

cf. doc https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#base